# Omitting twiddle factors in Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm

Tags: reference-request, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

The discrete Fourier transform
$$
X_k = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} x_m e^{-2\pi ikm/n}
$$
can be computed via [Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm)

The key of the algorithm is the butterfly transform, given by
$$
X_k = E_k + \omega^k \cdot O_k\\
X_{k + N/2} = E_k - \omega^k \cdot O_k\\
\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}}.
$$
The $\omega^k$ value is called "twiddle factor". I've implemented this algorithm and it worked flawlessly.

Then I've replaced twiddle factor with unity, making the butterfly transform look like
$$
X_k = E_k + O_k\\
X_{k + N/2} = E_k - O_k
$$
This looks very much like [Haar transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_matrix), but is different.

This transform has some remarkable properties:

- It transforms real data to real data
- Its matrix is symmetric
- Its matrix is orthogonal (up to $\sqrt{n}$ factor)
- It is self inverse (follows from previous two)
- Its matrix contains only $\pm 1$ (no zeros). Here's the matrix portrait for $n = 32$
  [image]

and the matrix for $n=8$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

There are some questions that interest me:

- Is this discrete transform known?
- Can it be expressed like DFT?
- Is there any convolution theorem for this transform?

**Update.** Here's an explicit formula I've obtained. Let $\vec k$ be the binary representation of $k$ treated as a vector in $\mathbb Z^d$. Then
$$
X_k = \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} x_m (-1)^{\vec k^\top J \vec m}
$$
where $J$ is the exchange matrix. In other words
$$
X_k = \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} x_m (-1)^{\phi(\vec k, \vec m)}
$$
and
$$
\phi(\vec k, \vec m) \equiv  \sum_{i = 1}^{d} k_i m_{d+1-i} = \phi(\vec m, \vec k), \qquad d = \log_2 n
$$

Also, removing bit-reversal permutation in CT algorithm leads to a similar transform with
$$
X_k = \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} x_m (-1)^{\psi(\vec k, \vec m)}\\
\psi(\vec k, \vec m) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^d k_i m_i = \psi(\vec k, \vec m).
$$

Comment: it doesn't look like a filter-bank transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform matrix is a Hadamard matrix, and the transform that you described is is known as [fast Walsh-Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform). See also the more general description of [Hadamard transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform).